# Magento 2 - How to get attribute of product?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

How to get attribute of product?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another way, for the custom attributes: we can simply get the value by using **getCustomAttribute()**

```
if (null !== $product->getCustomAttribute('your_custom_attribute')) {
   echo $product->getCustomAttribute('your_custom_attribute')->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Best practice in magento is to do it via xml.

To get a standard attribute you do something like this in `catalog_product_view.xml` for example:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.brand" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="brand"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

This will get the value of an input attribute or textarea. If you have a dropdown you should use the text type, so add this line in the list of arguments:

```
<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
```

No need to create files or write any php code to get an attribute. This way you'll use the same default php code for any attribute and you'll have to change it only once if needed.

Comment: Like your solution, changed <referenceBlock to <referenceContainer and it worked as "product.info.main" is a container :)

Answer (score 13):

I had solution for my issue:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
$attr = $product->getData('status');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$_product->getData('attr_code');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Please, try to use a block class such as "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" but I would recommend not to use Object Manager in Magento 2 unless as a last resort.

Answer (score 5):

Another way in phtml-files:

```
echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description')
```

as in: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/description.phtml`

Comment: this is a better way to do it than using object manager which is almost always discouraged.  +1

Comment: best solution that I found. +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Block inside the catalog_product_view.xml and add inside any container you want or create a container around it.

```
<!-- Get a attribute -->
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.attributes.Height" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getHeight</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">height</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">height</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="Height"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the original post, but how would I modify this method so I can pull a dynamic attribute set rather than specifying it in the catalog_product_view.xml file -  Block name="product.attribute.key-features" ?
The project I'm working on has many possible attribute sets all for the same Key Features section of the product page.
So one product may use attribute set A for it's key features and another product may use attribute set B for it's key features.
Andy Help appreciated.
Andy