# Special price product in product collection magento2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, price-rules, special-price

How do I get products with special price rule (for logged in customer group as well as overall) in product collection?

Comment: On which file u need `.phtml`?

Comment: no in my block... protected function _getProductCollection() {
    /** @var ProductCollection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

Comment: have you try to set tier price for `customer group` ?

Comment: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-product-attributes-with-name-and-value/ or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106809/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-of-product `$_product->getSpecialPrice()`

Comment: thank you..really appreciate this..but I am not looking for an attribute value...I want to list products with special price rules for the current date...

Comment: I tried this but did not work ,  $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array(
                                'attribute' => "special_to_date",
                                'null' => true
                            ),
                            array(
                                'attribute' => "special_to_date",
                                'from' => $todayDate,
                                //'to'      => $todayDate,
                                'date' => true
                            )
                        ));