# Magento 2 custom attribute and show product if attribute YES

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, custom

its very Urgent

I have an attribute called 'show_product'  (in the backend of Magento) with two outcomes 'yes' or 'no'. At the moment I'm just echoing the product name on the frontend. However, ideally I'd like to show all product name the attribute value. For example, if 'yes' then show all product, if 'no' then No product.

**Can anyone please help me.**

[image]

**I tried some this**

```
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\objectManager::getInstance(); 

            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($singleproductdata['entity_id']);
            $attributes = $product->getAttributes('show_product');
           foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

                    echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();   
                    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);   

            }
```

Comment: You means if Show product is set to yes you want to display on frontend if no then you dont have to display product name , am i correct?

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal yes u are correct

Comment: okay so I believe you should create a plugin after product collection and add addAttributeToFilter condition there.

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal you can do it because i tried but it didn't happen

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\objectManager::getInstance(); 

                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($singleproductdata['entity_id']);
                $attributes = $product->getAttributes('show_product');
               foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

                        echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();   
                        echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);   

                }

Comment: @DineshThakur you said if 'yes' then show all product. so 'show product' is for all product or for single product ? I think this is product edit screen and if yes then only, product should show on frontend right ?

Comment: @DimplePanchal i have 100 products if attribute yes show product and if No so product not display in custom  phtml template page

Comment: Please add your error

Answer (score 1):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($singleproductdata['entity_id']);
print_r($product->getCustomAttribute('show_product')->getValue());
```

**please check your product id has attribute value set or not**

[click here source link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106809/magento-2-how-to-get-attribute-of-product)

Comment: Thanks for reply let me check and update

Comment: Let me inform it's works or not ?

Comment: Sorry @Msquare this is not work

Comment: please share your error

Comment: check add link it's helps you.

Answer (score 1):

First get Your Product Collection and then

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('show_product');
```

Comment: I am new in magento 2, please suggest  how to create this functionality

Comment: you can load product collection by product id and then apply getAttribteText method on it

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\objectManager::getInstance(); 

                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($singleproductdata['entity_id']);
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('show_product');
               foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

                        echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();   
                        echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);   

                }
Right ?\

Answer (score 1):

For filtering, product collection create after plugin for  Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct for the function getLoadedProductCollection()

```
/**
 * Retrieve loaded category collection
 *
 * @return AbstractCollection
 */
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really do want to show the product in forntend you can use Visibility set to "Not visible individually"

[image]